# Is there any book depicting British rule in India from the eyes of British?

Tags: india, british-empire

Frankly speaking, most of the history written from the minds of Indians depict British as the brutal enemy. I am very tired of this view, as an Indian, I wanted to know any book depicting British rule in India from a British point of view.

Comment: Hello Bala, Welcome to History:SE!  Where have you looked so far - have you searched Amazon and Google?  If so, what were the results?  This site requests that Questions include initial research information.  Please be aware that as worded at present, this Question will likely be ruled as Off Topic due to either lack of your research results that have been unsatisfactory thuis far, or for being too broad.  Don't  get discouraged! Just try to help us help you!

Comment: Anything by Kipling?

Comment: "From the eyes of the British" is a confusing term since the actions of the East India Company were condemned severely by many including Adam Smith. You'll have to narrow it down to which section of British society you are talking about preferably including their political leanings.

Comment: @Rahul - since the only qualifier in the question was that the source be British, I would suggest that Adam Smith would still be a valid choice (among others, in order to weigh all British viewpoints in balance).

Comment: Besides Adam Smith, Edmund Burke also wrote about the EIC rule in India, in very unfavorable terms. Although, as far as I know, there are various essays and political speeches about India from him, but not an actual book.

Comment: British involvement in education, inequality (reservations), transportation.

Comment: @Bala Subramanian: Re inequality, you would have to consider how the British affected what was already a highly unequal society - the caste system, the vast wealth of many of the Indian rulers, &c.

Comment: British has done so many good things to the Indians. I am still asking how they removed inequality in India.Also why they hated Gandhi not Ambedkar.

Comment: @BalaSubramanian Please edit that information into your question. [Comments are ephemeral, and tend to get deleted](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3631/24858)

Comment: Guardian newspaper.

Answer (score 7):

One widely-read book in this vein is [*British India* by R. W. Frazer](https://archive.org/details/britishindia00fraziala), 1918, which you can consult on archive.org. See specifically Chapter XVI, "Moral and Material Progress Under British Rule".

Answer (score 3):

I very much enjoyed *Indian society and the making of the British Empire* by Christopher Bayly, published in 1988.

It is my understanding that this book has been somewhat influential in academic circles. It seems to be available in [LibGen](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/search.php?&req=indian+society&phrase=1&view=simple&column=def&sort=author&sortmode=ASC) if that is [legal in your country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_Genesis)